# Reloading <p:tree> from backing bean doesn't seem to work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, tree

I have this tree in my page:

```
<h:form id="form" >     

    <h:panelGrid columns="4" id="panel">

        <p:tree id="tree1"
                value="#{mybean.myObject}" 
                var="myObject" 
                selectionMode="single" 
                selection="#{mybean.selectedNode}"
                draggable="true" 
                droppable="true" 
                dragdropScope="myObjectTest">

            <p:ajax event="dragdrop" 
                    listener="#{mybean.onDragDrop}" 
                    update=":form:msgs" />

            <p:treeNode id="treeNode1">
                <div>
                    <h:outputText value="#{myObject.label}" />
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <p:commandLink update=":formDialogmyObject:myObjectPanel" oncomplete="PF('documentDialog').show()" title="View">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{myObject}" target="#{mybean.selectedmyObject}" />
                </p:commandLink>                    

            </p:treeNode>                
        </p:tree>            

        <p:tree id="tree2" 
                value="#{mybean.myObjectAvailable}" 
                var="myObjectAvailable"
                selectionMode="single" 
                selection="#{mybean.selectedNode}"
                draggable="true" 
                droppable="true" 
                dragdropScope="myObjectTest"
        >

            <p:ajax event="dragdrop" 
                    listener="#{mybean.onDragDropDelete}" 
                    update=":form:msgs" process="" />

            <p:treeNode>
                <h:outputText value="#{myObjectAvailable.label}" />
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>            

    </h:panelGrid>     

    <br />

</h:form>

<p:dialog 
    id="dialogmyObject"   
    showEffect="clip"
    hideEffect="clip"
    widgetVar="documentDialog" 
    modal="true" 
    resizable="false"
    appendTo="@(body)"
    binding="#{mybean.dialog}"
>

    <h:form id="formDialogmyObject" >

        <p:outputPanel id="myObjectPanel" >

            <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label,value" rendered="#{not empty mybean.selectedmyObject}">

                <h:outputLabel for="idmyObject" value="ID myObject" />
                <h:outputText id="idmyObject" value="#{mybean.selectedmyObject.idmyObject}" />

            </p:panelGrid>

            <br />

            <p:commandButton    
                id="cmdSaveSinglemyObjectItem"
                action="#{mybean.onSavemyObjectItem()}" 
                value="Save" 
                update=":form:tree1:treeNode1"
            />

        </p:outputPanel>

    </h:form>
```

In my bean, method "cmdSaveSinglemyObjectItem" do this:

```
//business logic for update data into database about menu item and update bean...
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form");
RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
rc.execute("PF('documentDialog').hide();");
rc.closeDialog(dialog);
```

Bean is updated correctly but tree component (id=tree1) isn't updated. View old value, but if I refresh page I view data updated...

Comment: Better include popup Window and use  `update="tree1"` I tried it previously it work for me.

Comment: I must use Primefaces...

Comment: Have you tried to use the same form for the dialog also?

Comment: @Diaboliko Who told you not use Primefaces? I told put popup code in another file and include it .

Comment: @Subodh Joshi: I will try but I prefer use same file for Dialog.

Comment: @David_Ware: if I use same form, the command button into dialog (id=cmdSaveSinglemyObjectItem) don't work, onlick nothing happened.

Comment: @Subodh Joshi: I tried to use a popup in another file. I set update="tree1" in Dialog commandButton but doesn't work... Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing happened? Is your backing method void, right? try to change your code:

<p:commandButton    
                id="cmdSaveSinglemyObjectItem"
  oncomplete="dialogmyObject.hide();
                actionListener="#{mybean.onSavemyObjectItem()}" 
                value="Save" 
                update=":form:tree1:treeNode1"
            />

Answer (score 0):

You should update the whole tree and not just a specific subelement of it.

```
update=":form:tree1"
```

instead of your `update=":form:tree1:treeNode1"`